# @ControllerAdvice, how to get the class which called this method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, controller-advice

Is there a way to get the class from where the `@ControllerAdvice` got its control.

**I.e.:** If and execution of PersonController is going on and I get some error due to which the control transferred to the `@ControllerAdvice` class's method `handleException(...)`.

Is there a way to get the `PersonController` class name inside the `handleException` method with Spring 3.2.3.

Any other way to achieve this?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `getStackTrace` against your exception, first entry will give you the originating class

```
 handleException(YourException ex) {
    String exceptionController = ex.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Now suppose if I am not rethrowing the exception at controller level, then in that case the class I will get will be manager layer class as the exception is thrown from there, is there a way that I can get the controller name?

Comment: How can I get the request Param?